# Displaying code in code elements, in a meta way

Tags: html, element

I am making a documentation page for free code camp. I am new to this, really new :). I want to display a carrot symbol and show how I code it into the page using the
 `&ltcode&gt` 
element. Of course when I do it on this website it doesn't make the carrots (don't know why that's the case either). But on codepen website, it does make those symbols into carrots. How do I write "&lt" and "&gt" in my code element to show how I make carrots within a code element to display without them automatically displaying as carrots themselves? I hope my question makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The "&" symbol has its own HTML Character Code as well, which is `&amp;`. So to show `&lt;` without it evaluating to the less than symbol, you would have to display the "&" symbol, which is `&amp;`, followed by `lt;`, like this:

```
&amp;lt;
```

The same works with the greater than symbol:

```
&amp;gt;
```

Good luck!